# "within walking distance to" vs "within walking distance of"

Tags: prepositions

Is this hotel within walking distance **to** the city centre?

Is this hotel within walking distance **of** the city centre?

***Which one to use?***

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to example of the Oxford Advanced Learner's Dictionary:

> The beach is within walking distance **of** my house

also you can use "the vicinity" like:

> Crowds gathered in the vicinity of Trafalgar Square